# How do I cut out part of an image at runtime and then use it later on

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a little platform game in WPF and I have trouble with the implementation of my character's and other objects' continuous movement. I could acquire the "model" images from another game (Little Fighter 2), but the problem is, that they look like this: [character movements image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsW3M.png)

How do I cut out only a part of this image whenever that part is needed? For example, when my character is running I want my app to cut out the first, second, and third "state" from the 3rd row and then change my character's look to these, altering between them fastly (making my character look like it's running). How do I tell my program which part should it cut out and to cut it out "perfectly" and not in a rectangle shape, so that it doesn't display the black background parts, but only the character?

Comment: This is called a sprite.

Comment: Although you could do this a number of ways within WPF, it is really the wrong tool for the job. MonoGame would be a much simpler tool for making games in this manner using C#; it will support sprites properly.